# SQL IF NULL From SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Why does this give me 1 which is what I was expecting:

```
IF (SELECT 123) = 123
    PRINT 1
ELSE
    PRINT 2
```

But this gives me 2 which I was not expecting:

```
IF (SELECT NULL) = NULL
    PRINT 1
ELSE
    PRINT 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` values are checked by `IS NULL`

you have to use:

```
IF (SELECT NULL) IS NULL
    PRINT 1
ELSE
    PRINT 2
```

from the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-null.html):

> To search for column values that are NULL, you cannot use an expr =
>   NULL test.  The following statement returns no rows, because expr =
>   NULL is never true for any expression

Answer (score 3):

If you put NULLS OFF

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
    IF (SELECT NULL) =  NULL
        PRINT 1
    ELSE
        PRINT 2
```

then you will get PRINT 1

Answer (score 1):

You cant check `NULL` with `=`. For that `IS` has to be used.
Ex:

```
IF (SELECT NULL) IS NULL
    PRINT 1
ELSE
    PRINT 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check `NULL` using `=`. You need to use `IS NULL` like the following

```
IF (SELECT NULL) IS NULL
    PRINT 1
ELSE
    PRINT 2
```